# I am trying to execute multiple test cases in different class but in same browser instance

Tags: selenium, maven

/****How to execute different test cases written in two different classes in the same browser instance?
I am developing basic hybrid framework(POM with PFM). In this framework I have written two page classes 1. Loginpage 2.HomePage and two test classes 1.LoginTest 2. HomePageTest. In LoginTest, I am verifying login test cases by providing data using excel sheet and it works perfectly fine. In HomePageTest class I want to verify search functionality after login.

Queries: 1. How can I use Login method(written in Loginpage class) in HomePageTest class to perform search after login? 2. I know there are multiple ways to call login method in HomePageTest class but what is the best approach? 3. Can I perform the execution of both test cases written in two different classes without closing and reopening the browser? If yes then How?****/

Here is my code: BaseClass:

```
package basePackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;


public class BaseClass {

public static WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({"browser", "baseUrl"})
    //@BeforeClass
    public static void intitialization(String browserName, String url)
    {
        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ambrish/Lockdown_Tets/SeleniumPractice/drivers/chromedriver");
            driver= new ChromeDriver();
            Reporter.log("Chrome Launched", true);
        }
        else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("FireFox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/ambrish/Lockdown_Tets/SeleniumPractice/drivers/geckodriver");
            driver= new FirefoxDriver();
            Reporter.log("Firefox Launched", true);
        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(url);

        Reporter.log(url+ "url navigated", true);

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result)
    {
        String scriptName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        if (result.isSuccess())     //true---> script pass
        {
            Reporter.log(scriptName+ "script is passed :)", true);
        }
        else  //false----> script failed
        {
           ScreenshotLib slib = new ScreenshotLib(driver);
           slib.takescreenshot(scriptName);
           Reporter.log("screenshot has been taken", true);
        }

        driver.close();
        Reporter.log("Browser closed", true);


    }
```

}

LoginPageClass:

```
package pageObject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.Reporter;

import basePackage.BaseClass;


public class LoginPage extends BaseClass {

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[contains(text(),'Login & Signup')]")
    private WebElement LoginLink;

    @FindBy(xpath="(//form/div/input[@type='text'])")
    private WebElement UnTxBx;

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='password']")
    private WebElement PwdTxBx;

    @FindBy(xpath="(//button[@type='submit'])[last()]")
    private WebElement loginBtn;

    @FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(text(),'Your username or password is incorrect')]")
    private WebElement invalidLoginMsg;


    //Intializing Page Object
    public LoginPage()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public  static void login(String username, String password)
    {
      UnTxBx.sendKeys(username);    
      PwdTxBx.sendKeys(password);
      loginBtn.click();
     }

}
```

HomePageClass:

```
package pageObject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import basePackage.BaseClass;
import basePackage.WaitStatementLib;

public class FKartHome extends BaseClass {
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@title='Search for products, brands and more']")
    private WebElement SearchSendKeys;


    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@type='submit']")
    private WebElement ClickSubmit;


    public FKartHome()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public  static void search(String searchBook)
    {
        WaitStatementLib.eWaitForVisible(20, SearchSendKeys);
        SearchSendKeys.sendKeys(searchBook);
        ClickSubmit.click();

    }

}
LoginPageTestClass:

package scriptTest;


import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import basePackage.BaseClass;
import basePackage.ExcelUtilities;
import pageObject.FKartHome;
import pageObject.LoginPage;

public class LoginPageTest extends BaseClass {
    public  static LoginPage  loginPage;

    @Test
    public static void loginTest()
    {
        String filepath= "/home/ambrish/Lockdown_Tets/SeleniumPractice/TestDataSheet/testdata.xlsx";
        String username = ExcelUtilities.readData(filepath, "sheet1", 1, 1);
        String password = ExcelUtilities.readData(filepath, "sheet1", 1, 2);
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
        loginPage .login(username, password);
    }
}
```

HomePageTestClass:

```
package scriptTest;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import basePackage.BaseClass;
import pageObject.FKartHome;
import pageObject.ItemsPage;
import pageObject.LoginPage;

public class FKartHomeTest extends BaseClass {

    public static FKartHome fKartHome;

    @Test
    public void searchBook()
    {

        String searchBook= "Books";
         fKartHome= new FKartHome();
         fKartHome.search(searchBook);

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your base class code. I believe that you have created the webdriver instance in that class. Please update this question with the BaseClass code as well

Comment: I have updated BasceClass code, inside base package